# Checking if two lists are equal at Nth position

Tags: haskell

I've just started learning Haskell as a module in my CS degree.

Currently trying to create a function which takes a list `[Int]` and a list `[Integer]`.

My goal is to check if the two lists are equal at the n-th position.

So far, i've been able to compare two [Int] lists to see if they're equal.

```
compareList :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool 
compareList x y = x == y
```

But i am unsure how to compare at the n-th position. If someone could help me that would be great.

Thanks in advance, 
sam

Comment: What if one or both of the lists are too short? How do you want to handle the fact that `Int` is bounded while `Integer` is conceptually unbounded?

Comment: For this i'm assuming that the numbers entered will be '830314'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming that element indexing starts at 0.)

The n:th element of a list is the same as the (n-1):th element of its tail, so we can use recursion over the lists.

It's easy to compare the first (0:th) position of two non-empty lists:

```
compareLists (x:xs) (y:ys) 0 = x == y
```

It's also easy if one or both of the lists is empty, if we adopt the convention that the n:th elements are unequal if they don't exist:

```
compareLists [] [] n = False
compareLists [] (y:ys) n = False
compareLists (x:xs) [] n = False
```

(These cases can be combined somewhat, but I'm spelling them out in the hope that it's clearer.)

And for the general case, take the tails of the two lists and compare their (n-1):th elements:

```
compareLists (x:xs) (y:ys) n = compareLists xs ys (n - 1)
```

Comment: Tried this, 'not in scope'

listCheck :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> Bool 
listCheck (x:xs) (y:ys) n = listCheck xs ys (n - 1)

Comment: @sam *What* is not in scope? (The code in the answer has been tested in ghci.)

Comment: Im getting 'compareLists not in scope' 

Here is my full code; 
compareLists :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
compareLists (x:xs) (y:ys) n = compareLists xs ys (n - 1)

Comment: @sam The type is `[Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> Bool`.

Comment: Ok i've changed that and still getting scope error. It prints: 
          Not in scope: ‘compareLists’
          Perhaps you meant ‘compareList’ (line 2)

Thanks for assisting me.

Comment: @sam You defined 'compareList', but you're using 'compareList**s**'. I get that error if I misspell the function when I apply it.

Comment: where have I defined the function as 'compareList' I'm checking my code and everything seems to be spelt compareLists even when i call the function in the ghci

Comment: @sam We can't see your code so you'll just have to take the compiler's word for it.